# Get Youtube Iframe State While Chromecasting

Tags: javascript, youtube, chromecast, youtube-iframe-api

I have a page that uses the Youtube iFrame api to embed a Youtube player.  I use this player to send Youtube videos to the **default** Youtube receiver application on my Chromecast device.

I noticed that the events thrown by the player aren't the same when it's connected to a Chromecast.  For example, it never says that it's paused or playing even if it is playing on Chromecast.

My question is, is there a way to know if the embedded Youtube player is connected to a device to better handle these events?

Thanks!